# How to remove this title bar off window from gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

How can I remove this title-bar  `Ubuntu Start Page - Mozilla Firefox` like thing off browser/window from gnome-shell?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Simply add this extension to get rid of the title bar and reclaim your screen space:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/

It has the added benefit that you still get maximise/minimise buttons but these are now stowed away in the top panel.